# I write this module to arithmetic shift to left and right in verilog

Tags: verilog, hdl, modelsim

this is my code:

```
module zero(out,A,B);
   output signed[5:0] out;
   input signed[5:0] A,B;
   assign out = A[5:0]<<<2 + B[5:0]>>>1;
endmodule
```

but the output is always zero.

is there anything wrong?

(I don't want to use @always)

Comment: is this a school assignment?

Comment: Can you share your testbench?

Comment: How do you know that the output is always zero?

Comment: I am new to hardware description languages and because of this i can't handle this @jsotola

Comment: Please answer the three questions that were asked in the first three comments to your question. Even if you are new to HDL you should be able to answer these questions.

Comment: I test my module by force the inputs in modelSim

Comment: Or rather, a minimal testbench that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I test different inputs and for all of them the result was zero

Comment: for example i put A = 16 and B = 2 and the output was zero

Comment: Did you allow the simulation to run for a non-zero time after forcing the inputs?

Comment: Also, what were you expecting to get for `16<<<2` in 6-bit signed arithmetic?

Comment: certainly yes i allowed

Comment: 16 in binary form is 10000 so when I shift it two bit right so the result is 1000000 that is equal to 64

Comment: Okay, but 1. a [5:0] signed value can't hold 7'b1000000. And 2. Even if it did, it would treat the high bit as a sign bit, so the value wouldn't be 64, it would be -63.

Comment: ok.but for example if A=10 and B is 10 in binary form,then the result of A<<<2 + B>>>1 is 1000 + 1 = 1001 that is equal to 9 in decimal;do you agree with me?

Comment: We really need to see your testbench for this. "Forcing the inputs in Modelsim" is not really a thing.

Comment: Next issue is operator precedence. According to [this](http://www.asic-world.com/systemverilog/operators4.html), `+` has higher precedence than `<<<`, so your expression will calculate `(A <<< (2 + B)) >>> 1` rather than what you might expect. (I am not 100% confident in that source on the precedence though)

Comment: I think the precedence is as same as you said here,I take some parentheses and my problem was solved.thank you very much for your step by step helping sir.

Comment: On another page they say `+` and `<<` precedence are equal (not listing `<<<`), which would imply you calculate `((A << 2) + B) >> 1` instead of what you expect. What happens if you just fully parenthesize your expression to be sure to get the right order of operations?

Comment: I got the right answer as i said in last comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From our discussion in comments, it seems the problem is operator precedence. According to [this](http://www.asic-world.com/systemverilog/operators4.html), `+` has higher precedence than `<<<`, so your expression will calculate `(A <<< (2 + B)) >>> 1` rather than what you might expect.

This can be solved by adding parentheses to ensure the expected order of operations.